# CPAN install Module::Install fails passing tests (strawberryperl)

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I'm completely new to Perl, so maybe there is something obvious I'm not seeing.

I'm using perl to compile PostgreSQL database (C++) and I need to call an "install" command (here there are PostgreSQL [installation instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/install-windows-full.html), and [source files](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=tree;f=src/tools/msvc;hb=HEAD) with code used), this is the output:

```
Can't locate Install.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Install module) 
(@INC contains: shows/me/several/directories/
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at install.pl line 9.
```

Searching internet about this error, I found that I have to install `Module::Install` and here comes the error:

```
$ cpan Module::Install
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Mon, 11 Sep 2017 15:32:15 GMT

Running install for module 'Module::Install'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.96)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for C:\Users\e047439\.conan\data\strawberryperl\5.26.0\conan\stable\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\cpan\sources\authors\id\E\ET\ETHER\Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.26)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.65)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20170530)
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
include C:/Users/e047439/.conan/data/strawberryperl/5.26.0/conan/stable/package/ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187/cpan/build/Module-Install-1.18-4/inc/Module/Install.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Metadata.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Makefile.pm
include inc/Module/Install/With.pm
include inc/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Win32.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Can.pm
include inc/Module/Install/Fetch.pm
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Module::Install
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing META.yml
  ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz
  C:\Users\e047439\.conan\data\strawberryperl\5.26.0\conan\stable\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Makefile.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Makefile.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Compiler.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Compiler.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Manifest.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Manifest.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Metadata.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Metadata.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Include.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Include.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Bundle.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Bundle.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Can.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Can.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/WriteAll.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\WriteAll.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Base.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Base.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Find.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Find.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/ScanDeps.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\ScanDeps.pm
cp lib/Module/Install.pod blib\lib\Module\Install.pod
cp lib/Module/Install.pm blib\lib\Module\Install.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Admin/Bundle.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Admin\Bundle.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/AutoInstall.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\AutoInstall.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/API.pod blib\lib\Module\Install\API.pod
cp lib/Module/AutoInstall.pm blib\lib\Module\AutoInstall.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/With.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\With.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Run.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Run.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Deprecated.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Deprecated.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/PAR.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\PAR.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Scripts.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Scripts.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Win32.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Win32.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Fetch.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Fetch.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Include.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Include.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/MakeMaker.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\MakeMaker.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Makefile.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Makefile.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Philosophy.pod blib\lib\Module\Install\Philosophy.pod
cp lib/Module/Install/Share.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Share.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Compiler.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Compiler.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/WriteAll.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\WriteAll.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Metadata.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Metadata.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/Inline.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\Inline.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/External.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\External.pm
cp lib/Module/Install/FAQ.pod blib\lib\Module\Install\FAQ.pod
cp lib/Module/Install/DSL.pm blib\lib\Module\Install\DSL.pm
cp lib/inc/Module/Install.pm blib\lib\inc\Module\Install.pm
cp lib/inc/Module/Install/DSL.pm blib\lib\inc\Module\Install\DSL.pm
  ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz
  C:\Users\e047439\.conan\data\strawberryperl\5.26.0\conan\stable\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\c\bin\gmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Users\e047439\.conan\data\strawberryperl\5.26.0\conan\stable\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t t/recursive/*.t
t/01_compile.t .......................... ok
t/02_mymeta.t ........................... skipped: New EU::MM has own MYMETA support
t/03_autoinstall.t ...................... skipped: Skipping dangerous test
t/04_version.t .......................... ok
t/05_share.t ............................ 3/22
#   Failed test 'make'
#   at t/05_share.t line 37.

#   Failed test 'Found install_share in correct dist_dir location'
#   at t/05_share.t line 40.

#   Failed test 'Found expected file in dist_dir location'
#   at t/05_share.t line 43.
open(t\Foo39760\blib\lib\auto\share\dist\Foo\dist_file.txt): No such file or directory at (eval 27) line 3.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 6.
t/05_share.t ............................ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 19/22 subtests
t/06_ppport.t ........................... ok
t/07_perl_version.t ..................... ok
t/08_dsl.t .............................. ok
t/09_read.t ............................. ok
t/10_test.t ............................. ok
t/11_extraction.t ....................... ok
t/12_eumm_params.t ...................... ok
t/13_author_tests.t ..................... ok
t/13_author_tests_ext.t ................. skipped: requires Module::Install::AuthorTests
t/13_author_tests_ext2.t ................ skipped: requires Module::Install::ExtraTests 0.007
t/14_auto_include_deps_with_version.t ... skipped: your perl is new enough to have File::Spec 3.30 in core
t/15_wrong_usage.t ...................... ok
t/16_require.t .......................... ok
t/17_sign.t ............................. ok
t/18_all_from.t ......................... ok
t/19_authors.t .......................... ok
t/20_authors_with_special_characters.t .. ok
t/21_makemaker_args.t ................... ok
t/22_installdirs.t ...................... 12/24 old INSTALLDIRS (probably set by makemaker_args) is overriden by installdirs
t/22_installdirs.t ...................... ok
t/23_pl_files.t ......................... ok
t/24_multiple_license_blocks.t .......... ok
t/25_perl_version_from.t ................ ok
t/26_unknown_func.t ..................... ok
t/27_build_requires_and_include.t ....... 1/14 Warning: prerequisite Test::More 9999 not found. We have 1.302085.
t/27_build_requires_and_include.t ....... ok
t/28_makemaker_args.t ................... ok
t/29_requires_from.t .................... ok
t/30_build_subdirs.t .................... ok
t/31_add_metadata.t ..................... ok
t/32_module_name.t ...................... ok
t/33_copy.t ............................. ok
t/34_readwrite.t ........................ ok
t/recursive/test.t ...................... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/05_share.t                          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 6 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  4-6
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 22 tests but ran 6.
Files=37, Tests=541, 76 wallclock secs ( 0.25 usr +  0.25 sys =  0.50 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/37 test programs. 3/541 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:823: test_dynamic] Error 255
  ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz
  C:\Users\e047439\.conan\data\strawberryperl\5.26.0\conan\stable\package\ca33edce272a279b24f87dc0d4cf5bbdcffbc187\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports ETHER/Module-Install-1.18.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Module::Install'.
```

Some tests are failing and I don't know neither how to bypass it nor to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the original command that was failing when you were trying to compile PostgreSQL? `Module::Install` is not the same as `Install`.

Comment: Don't pass `-f` to `cpan`!!! It makes no sense to install a module that doesn't work! (It's a good thing you passed it last, cause that caused it to be ignored.)

Comment: Did you perhaps do `cpan Install ...` when you should have done `cpan install ...`?

Comment: @ikegami I tried it with and without the `-f`, one of the last attemps was to force instalation (and skip tests). I will edit the question to remove it. Thanks.

Comment: I know what `-f` does. I repeat, don't force installation!!! It makes no sense to install a module that doesn't work!

Comment: @melpomene, last step after compilation sources is to install binaries (link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/install-windows-full.html). The install script executed is this one: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/tools/msvc/install.pl;hb=HEAD

Comment: @ikegami, yes, I run `install c:\destination\...` and I get the first error (first codeblock in the question body), then I search through internet about it and it seems than I need to install `Module::Install`, so I run `cpan` and get the second error (second codeblock).

Answer (score 2):

Many scripts assume the script's directory is in `@INC`. That usually worked because the scripts's directory often happened to be the same as the CWD, and the CWD (`.`) was in `@INC`. But it wasn't always the case, and it's virtually never the case now that `.` is no longer in `@INC`.

In `src/tools/msvc/install.pl`,

Before the following:

```
use Install qw(Install);
```

Add the following:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

Comment: So, do you mean that it will work if I run the script inside the `src/tools/msvc/` directory? I think that I was doing it that way, I will try it using appveyor now, until tomorrow I won't have a Windows available.

But, if the code can be improved/fixed, you can send your proposal to PostgreSQL team.

Comment: Re "*do you mean that it will work if I run the script inside the src/tools/msvc/ directory*", No, now that `.` is no longer in `@INC`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have tried it in my windows machine and it has worked (running PostgreSQL install command) as expected.

May I keep the question opened as the title talks about why Module::Install fails (nothing to do with PostgreSQL)?